# Reading pandas dataframe that contains dictionaries in cells from csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I saved a pandas dataframe that looks like the following as a csv file.

```
    a
0 {'word': 5.7}
1 {'khfds': 8.34}
```

When I attempt to read the dataframe as shown below, I receive the following error.

```
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', index_col=0, dtype={'str': 'dict'})

TypeError: data type "dict" not understood
```

The heart of my question is how do I read the csv file to recover the dataframe in the same form as when it was created.  I also have tried reading **without** the **dtype={}** as well as **replacing** **'dict'** with alternatives such as 'dictionary', 'object', and 'str'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSV files may only contain text, so dictionaries are out of scope. Therefore, you need to read the text literally to convert to `dict`. One way is using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""a
{'word': 5.7}
{'khfds': 8.34}""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr)

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(literal_eval)

print(df['a'].apply(lambda x: type(x)))

0    <class 'dict'>
1    <class 'dict'>
Name: a, dtype: object
```

However, I strongly recommend you do **not** use Pandas specifically to store pointers to dictionaries. Pandas works best with contiguous memory blocks, e.g. separate numeric data into numeric series.

Comment: What would you suggest for storing dictionaries?

Comment: My suggestion is to reformat. Have one column for your string keys, another column for your numeric values. There are many questions on SO on this, but your'e welcome to ask a fresh question for this if you get stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do the conversion to dictionary directly while reading the csv files as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""a
{'word': 5.7}
{'khfds': 8.34}""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, converters={'a': literal_eval})

print(df.iloc[0]['a']['word'])
```

Comment: doing the conversion at this stage, rather than in an apply call after the read in, helped me avoid a ValueError: malformed node or string: nan issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment)
Even after giving ast.literal_eval I had the "ValueError: malformed node or string" on some dict columns.

Fixing the spacing in dict, fixed the issue for me.
example -

before

`ast.literal_eval("{'word' : 5.7}, {'khfds' : 8.34}")`

after

`ast.literal_eval("{'word': 5.7}, {'khfds': 8.34}")`

hope this helps someone

Answer (score -3):

You may also use the plain and simple python eval as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""a
{'word': 5.7}
{'khfds': 8.34}""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr)

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(eval)

print(df['a'].apply(lambda x: type(x)))

0    <class 'dict'>
1    <class 'dict'>
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the above one!?